# Toggle Switch hangs when changing state

Tags: thingsboard

Hello I am running ThingsBoard version 3.5.1. I am trying to use the Slide Toggle Control widget on my dashboard. Whenever I slide the switch, from ON to OFF and vice versa, it takes forever to change the state of the switch. See here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eddPD.png)

I tried toggling the switch but it just hangs.

Comment: Can you please specify if it's cloud or self-managed ?

Comment: Can you define how this widget is configured? Usually this will involve some RPC command to a target entity/device.

Comment: @Kalaivanan, these are the current configurations:

Value Settings:
Initial value - unchecked

Retrieve on/off value settings:
* retrieve value using method - subsscribe for timeseries

Update value settings:
RPC set value method - setValue

RPC settings:
RPC request timeout - 500ms

Persistent RPC settings:
RPC request persistent - checked

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t, our ThingsBoard instance is self managed and hosted in the cloud (digital ocean)

Comment: Is your device & firmware capable of handling the RPC command **setValue** ? In other words is setValue one of the RPC calls that your device can handle?